# izpack : error in executing java class from panel izpack

Tags: izpack

I use izpack for creating installer. I need to execute a java class from the process panel, so I created jar file for my java class ServiceChecker, added job in ProcessPanel.Spec.xml and included them in the installer.xml file.

**ServiceChecker**

```
public void run(AbstractUIProcessHandler handler, String[] args){
        handler.logOutput("Checking Service.", false);      
}
......// ServiceChecking method.
```

**ProcessPanel.Spec.xml**

```
<Processing>
    <logfiledir>$INSTALL_PATH</logfiledir>  
    <job name="setup">
        <os family="windows" />
        <executeclass name="ServiceChecker">
            <arg>${myvariable}</arg>
        </executeclass>
    </job>      
    <onFail previous="true" next="false" />
    <onSuccess previous="false" next="true" />
</Processing>
```

**Installer.xml**

```
<resources>
        <res id="LicencePanel.licence" src="Licence.txt" />
        <res id="InfoPanel.info" src="Readme.txt" />
        <res id="Heading.image" src="My_header.png" />
        <res id="Installer.image" src="My_logo.jpg" />
        <res id="userInputSpec.xml" src="UserInput.Spec.xml"  />
        <res id="shortcutSpec.xml" src="shortcutSpec.xml" />
        <res id="CustomLangpack.xml" src="CustomLangpack.xml" />
        <res id="ProcessPanel.Spec.xml" src="ProcessPanel.Spec.xml"/>
    </resources>

<jar src="lib/ServiceChecker.jar" stage="install"/>

<panels>
    <panel classname="HelloPanel" />
    <panel classname="LicencePanel" />
    <panel classname="ProcessPanel"/>
    <panel classname="UserInputPanel" id="install.type.panel" />
    <panel classname="UserInputPanel" id="reg.panel" condition="standardinstallation"/>
    <panel classname="TreePacksPanel" />
    <panel classname="InstallPanel" />
    <panel classname="ShortcutPanel" />
    <panel classname="FinishPanel" />
</panels>
```

All methods in the jar executes successfully but the installer throws the following error.

> error when running processing class: ServiceChecker, com/izforge/izpack/api/handler/AbstractUIHandler

so unable to continue the installation. What's wrong with the java class run method? I followed the documentation [Executing a Java Class with ProcessPanel](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/Executing+a+Java+Class+with+ProcessPanel)